# How to verify in protractor navigation to 3rd party page such login with your Google account?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

We have options to log in with 3rd party providers using your Google or Microsoft accounts. I just need to verify that when you click on the link you get taken to the right provider page. After the page is loaded, I get:

```
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page
```

Seems the WebDriver instance is disconnected. What's the proper way to verify you've landed in a 3rd party site using protractor?

Comment: It seems that protractor only knows how to talk to angularJS pages - once you've navigated away to a 3rd party OAuth login page you can't use it anymore. I've tried 
    var driver = new webdriver
        .Builder()
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
        .build();
and not gotten anywhere with it.

Comment: Got it:         var webDriver = browser.driver;
        $("h4 a[href='/auth/logon/Google']")
          .click()
          .then(function () {
            webDriver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
              console.log(url);
              expect(url).toContain('accounts.google');
            });
          });

Comment: So, the trick is, cache off the instance of the webDriver before taking the action that navigates to a 3rd party page. When you get there, assuming you're still in the same browser instance, you can use the cached instance of the webDriver and make calls directly on that to get the current URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor waits until angular is done loading to proceed with your test. It will show you that error because you are going to a non-angular URL. To test non-angular pages you should use the webdriver api directly.

You can access webdriver through `browser.driver`

Here is an example:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js

You can find some documentation here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#setting-up-the-system-under-test